# Camanjs filter done callback (events in camanjs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, camanjs

I try to understand events in `camanjs`, but I need some examples. Can everyone write me simple example about this:

**1)** load image in to `canvas` (done)

```
Caman("#canvas-img2", base64_or_path_to_image, function () {
    this.nostalgia();
    this.render();
});
```

**2)** listen to end filtering, for `callback` with `this.toBase64()`

In docs, I found event page, but don't understand how it works.

Answer (score 5):

It was simple! Put callback in render, like this (I need to send base64 data to backend):

```
Caman("#canvas-img2", base64_or_path_to_image, function () {
        this.vintage();
        this.render(function() {
            FACE.camanPhoto = this.toBase64();
            base64Data = FACE.camanPhoto.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/,"");
            sendDataToServer();
        });
    })
```

Comment: I had no idea I could pass a function into render, you made my day so much better! I haven't had any luck with their event registration system when re-using a canvas.